# Devtools Install_github failes for Reprtree

Tags: r, github, devtools

Searched the whole internet, but couldn't find a solution.

Wrestling now for hours with this problem.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("araastat/reprtree")
```

But I receive an error every time (tried multiple things, like restarting, turn off my vpn).

> ```
> Installation failed: Command failed (1)
> Warning message:
> S3 methods ‘[.git_tree’, ‘as.POSIXct.git_time’, ‘as.character.git_time’, ‘as.data.frame.git_commit’,
> ```
>
> ‘as.data.frame.git_repository’, ‘as.data.frame.git_tree’,
>   ‘as.list.git_tree’, ‘diff.git_repository’, ‘diff.git_tree’,
>   ‘format.git_blob’, ‘format.git_commit’, ‘format.git_merge_result’,
>   ‘format.git_note’, ‘format.git_signature’, ‘format.git_tag’,
>   ‘head.git_repository’, ‘length.git_blob’, ‘length.git_diff’,
>   ‘length.git_tree’, ‘merge.character’, ‘merge.git_branch’,
>   ‘merge.git_repository’, ‘plot.git_repository’, ‘print.git_blob’,
>   ‘print.git_branch’, ‘print.git_commit’, ‘print.git_config’,
>   ‘print.git_diff’, ‘print.git_merge_result’, ‘print.git_note’,
>   ‘print.git_reference’, ‘print.git_reflog’, ‘print.git_reflog_entry’,
>   ‘print.git_repository’, ‘print.git_signature’, ‘print.git_status’,
>   ‘print.git_tag’, ‘print.git_time’, ‘print.git_tree’, ‘sha.git_blob’,
>   ‘sha.git_branch’, ‘sha.git_commit’, ‘sha.git_fetch_head’,
>   ‘sha.git_merge_result’, ‘sha.git_note’, ‘sha.git_reference’,
>   ‘sha.git_reflog_entry’, [... truncated]

**Edit. Another approach (as mentioned in the comments)**

```
devtools::install("reprtree-master")

Installing reprtree
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/bin/i386/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/asdf/Downloads/reprtree-master" --library="C:/Users/asdf/Documents/R/win-library/3.4" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'reprtree' ...
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'reprtree'
    finding HTML links ... done
    ReprTree                                html  
    finding level-2 HTML links ... done

    plot.getTree                            html  
    plot.reprtree                           html  
    reprtree-package                        html  
    snip.depth                              html  
    text.tree                               html  
Error: C:/Users/asdf/Downloads/reprtree-master/man/text.tree.Rd:41: Bad \link text
* removing 'C:/Users/asdf/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/reprtree'
In R CMD INSTALL
Error: Command failed (1)
>
```

Comment: download the zip, unzip and use devtools::install("theunzipedfile")

Comment: Do you have devtools installed? I've run it and had no problems.

Comment: @s.brunel already tried that: same error: Error: Command failed (1)

Comment: @Leo yes. I reinstalled devtools to be sure. Same error: Error: Command failed (1)

Comment: you probably don't have admin rights?
the error is here:
`Error: C:/Users/asdf/Downloads/reprtree-master/man/text.tree.Rd:41: Bad \link text`

Comment: @SatZ is there a workaround for that?

Comment: If you don't need it for a package, you can just use `devtools::load_all(location)` temporarily

Answer (score 2):

**For future readers**

Something is wrong in `text.tree.RD` at line 41. What I did propably isn't the most perfect solution, but it works.

You can [download](https://github.com/araastat/reprtree) the package as a `.zip` and unzip it. Then remove everything after line 39 in `./man/text.tree.RD`. Afterwards you can install the package like this:

```
library(devtools)
if(!('reprtree' %in% installed.packages())){
    install_local('path_to_extracted_zip/reprtree-master/')
}
```

Comment: The owner of the repo didn't update since 9 years so I don't expect he will accept the PR requetst but I have forked it and modified it so it works 

 remotes::install_github('munoztd0/reprtree')

Answer (score 0):

Try `devtools` but from different sources:

```
install.packages('devtools', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')
library(devtools)

devtools::install_github('skinner927/reprtree')
library(reprtree)
```